QGIS: Using HTML "other widget" in feature attribute form - white space below text
I am currently creating a QGIS template with a standardised feature attribute form upon feature creation. It would be very useful to have text explainers on some of the tabs I've created, I can use plain text but this looks pretty ugly and requires forcing line breaks as far as I can tell - no dynamic width adjustment.
I have tried using the HTML widget in the drag-drop feature form designer as this has dynamic width adjustment, however, even with very simple HTML there is a huge amount of white space below the text. This seems to replicate between QGIS versions - currently on the latest LTR. It also seems to be separate from CSS - any css I write in just creates a box within this white box.

The html code - very simple. Only using h3 and p.

Part of the drag drop designer.

The form when inputting feature attributes - the window would be big enough to have all of the feature info without expanding or scrolling if this white space wasn't there. You can also see some kinda ugly plain text at the top with a forced break.
Is it possible to do anything about this or should I just revert to plain text - or simply have everything in a ReadMe doc? Is the HTML widget even meant for this?

HTML code here, again, v. simple:
    <h3>Using Myndun and Jarðmyndun</h3>

    <p>The following is an English description of definitions that can be used here. This is a suggestion of use and is not currently defined in Fitjuskrá.</p>

    <p><strong>Myndun:</strong> Let's write a longish bit of text that should run over two lines but doesn't have any bearing on what the original text actually was. Hopefully this is about long enough don't you think?</p>


